# What do I do with the statue girl in Majula's secret area?

Tags: dark-souls-2

I've looked on other sites and they lead me in the wrong place, I want to know how to eather lift the cruse that was set on the poor girl, or could I remove the thing instead?

Comment: Give the poor girl some clothes? Maybe she'll teach you a thing or two about fire...

Comment: She's a freakin' statue! How am I to do that? Or was that an answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As with any petrified NPC, you can restore her to her normal form by using a Fragrant Branch of Yore. Interact with the statue with a branch in your inventory, and you'll receive a prompt asking if you'd like to free the NPC.

You'll encounter a handful of Fragrant Branches of Yore throughout your travels, so don't worry if you don't have any right now.

Comment: Yeah but where to do I get this item? Are there like hotspot that I could go I've been to:things betwixted, forest of fallen giants, hides tower of flame, and no mans wharf, any in these such regions?

Comment: I wasn't sure if you were interested in spoilers, so I didn't provide any specifics. [However, you can find the locations of all of the branches here.](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Fragrant+Branch+of+Yore)

Comment: I don't care for spoilers but I've already figured ouT there's one at the bottom of that pit majula some I'm trying to get enough money for the cat ring

Comment: Once you use the Fragrent Branch of Yore the next area leads to stuff that you can only access later on (with certain items, or conditions met), it's not an early game priority really. (Unless you're ready for it of course!)

Answer (score -2):

Get the cat ring and jump down on to each platform in the pit in majula